# pass input value to url delete method laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

i have form in my delete modal, and i want to pass hidden input to url method delete/destroy
this is my delete modal :

```
            <form action="{{url('/pages').'/' ... }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
            {{csrf_field()}}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Are you sure to delete this Page ?</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="page_id" style="display: none;">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="save">Delete</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">{{__('Close')}}</button>
            </form>
```

how to append input value(page_id) to form action ?
so i can use that page_id in form action :

```
<form action="{{url('/pages').'/'page_id}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

can some one help me ? thanks before :)

Comment: Do you have individual modal or one common modal?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a new attribute on each delete button contains the id.

please check the following code

```js
    $('.delete-button').click(function(){
        var pageId = $(this).data('page-id');
        $('.page_id').html(pageId);
        $('#modal-form').attr('action', deleteUrl+pageId);
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <a href="#" class="delete-button" data-page-id="1">page 1 </a>
    <a href="#" class="delete-button" data-page-id="2">page 2 </a>
    <a href="#" class="delete-button" data-page-id="3">page 3 </a>


    <form action="#" id="modal-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="">Are you sure to delete this Page <span class="page_id"></span>?</label>
    </form>

    <script>
       /* window.deleteUrl = "{{url('/pages').'/'}}"; // save globally */
       window.deleteUrl = "http://test.com/"; // temporary
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using boostrap modal then you have to pass data from that button something like this,

```
<button id="submit-btn" data-action="{{route('test')}}">Submit</button>
```

In JS,
replace modal's action with `data-action`.

Something like this,

`$('#form-id').val($('#submit-btn').data('action))`

And if you are not using modal then just store that `id` in variable and pass in route directly.

Hope it helps :)